# How do I compute the integral $\int\limits_0^1 t^a(1/2 - t)^b\ dt$?

Tags: integration, beta-function

I can write, $\int\limits_0^1 t^a(1/2 - t)^b\ dt = 2^{-(a+b)}\int_0^1 (2t)^a(1 - 2t)^b\ dt$.

Now, to compute $\int\limits_0^1 (2t)^a(1 - 2t)^b\ dt$, I can perform a substitution: compose the integrand with the function $u \mapsto u/2$ to get $\int_0^1 (2t)^a(1 - 2t)^b\ dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 u^a(1 - u)^b\ du$.

But what is $\int\limits_0^2 u^a(1 - u)^b\ du$? Is this some kind of Beta integral?

Comment: Perhaps an incomplete Beta function?

Comment: *Mathematica*:  For $\{ a, b\} >0$, $$2^{-a-b-1} \left((-1)^{b+1} B_{\frac{1}{2}}(-a-b-1,b+1)+\frac{\pi  \Gamma (b+1)
   \left((-1)^b \csc (\pi  (a+b))-\csc (\pi  a)\right)}{\Gamma (-a) \Gamma
   (a+b+2)}\right)$$

Comment: You’re going to run into issues. When $1/2<t<1$, $1/2-t<0$ so depending on the value of $b$, $(1/2-t)^b$ could be complex

Comment: Are $(a,b >0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the problem more general
$$\int\limits_0^1 t^a(c - t)^b\, dt \qquad \text{with} \qquad 0< c \leq 1$$ no problem with the antiderivative
$$\int t^a(c - t)^b\, dt =c^{a+b+1} B_{\frac{t}{c}}(a+1,b+1)$$ No problem with
$$I=\int\limits_0^c t^a(c - t)^b\, dt=c^{a+b+1}\frac{\Gamma (a+1)\, \Gamma (b+1) }{\Gamma (a+b+2)}\quad \text{if}\quad   \Re(b)>-1\land \Re(a)>-1$$

If $ \Re(b)>-1\land \Re(a)>-1$
$$\int\limits_c^1 t^a(c - t)^b\, dt=(-1)^b c^{a+b+1}\frac{\Gamma (b+1) \Gamma (-a-b-1)-\Gamma (-a) B_c(-a-b-1,b+1)}{\Gamma (-a)}$$ and the problem comes from the $\color{red}{(-1)^b}$ term.

For illustartion, using $c=\frac 1 2$, $a=2$ and $b=3+\frac k{10}$, the result is
$$I(k)=\frac{250- (-1)^{k/10}\, 5(k^2+100k+2450) }{2^{3+\frac{k}{10}}\, (k+40) (k+50) (k+60) }$$ and the values are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \text{numerical result} \\
  0 & -0.012500\, \\
  1 & -0.010863\,-0.003604 \, i \\
  2 & -0.008427\,-0.006268 \, i \\
  3 & -0.005557\,-0.007892 \, i \\
  4 & -0.002603\,-0.008490 \, i \\
  5 & +0.000137\,-0.008173 \, i \\
  6 & +0.002434\,-0.007118 \, i \\
  7 & +0.004138\,-0.005547 \, i \\
  8 & +0.005179\,-0.003694 \, i \\
  9 & +0.005563\,-0.001780 \, i \\
 10 & +0.005357\,
\end{array}
\right)$$

the numerical values are

Comment: Wow, thank you very much